# Using mutex to control thread and timer elapsed event

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, timer

In a component I need to receive data via UDP while my application must be responsible, so I created a Thread inside this component class for UDP listening. When data is received there must be two actions with a delay of 20ms between. There must always follow action 2 after action 1.

So I created a Timer and a mutex instance. After receiving the data the mutex is locked so Action 1 can't be executed, while Action 2 was not. After the timer is elapsed, the event handler is called, where the second action is processed and the mutex is released. That's the plan in theory.

But I get an error that the mutex is not locked, when I try to release it.

```
Imports System.Timers

Public Class CriticalActionProcessor
    Private mTimer As System.Timers.Timer
    Private mTimerMutex As Threading.Mutex

    Private mReceiveThread As Threading.Thread

    Public Sub New()
        ' do some initalizing

        mReceiveThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ProcessUDP)
        mReceiveThread.IsBackground = True
        mReceiveThread.Start()

        mTimer = new Timer()
        mTimerMutex = New Threading.Mutex()
        AddHandler mTimer.Elapsed, Sub()
                                        ' do some things, that must happen after some time
                                        mTimerMutex.ReleaseMutex() ' here it throws an exception 
                                                                   ' because mutex is not locked
                                   End Sub
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessUDP
        Dim udpReceiver = New UdpClient(5668)
        Dim ipEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5668)

        While (True)
            Dim receivedData As Byte() = udpReceiver.Receive(ipEndPoint)
            ' check received data
            mTimerMutex.WaitOne()
            Fire()
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub Fire()  
        ' do some things and after that start timer
        mTimer.Interval = 20
        mTimer.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

It seems that the Mutex is not shared by the UDP thread and the timer thread. How can I prevent that the Fire() method is called a second time before the timer elapsed handler was called?

Comment: You could have two threads, one that receive and put the data in a queue and the other that process what is in the queue. Between the two action, you could just do a sleep instead of a timer.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

Your main problem here is your misunderstanding on how Mutex work. Mutex is a lock, that once taken, can only be released by the thread which took it.

Consider a lock for the restroom. If John enters in there and locks himself to do his stuff, there is no way Arnold can remove the lock...

That's what you do here, one thread (ProcessUDP) takes the lock, and the timer (which is on another thread) tries to release it...

**A solution**

My first guess would be to call your first action before calling the Timer and your second action inside the sub for the timer :

```
'In the sub new, this is actually the second action
AddHandler mTimer.Elapsed, Sub() 
                                 'Do your second action here, 
                                 'since it will be called after the timer is done
                           End Sub

'This would be the first action
Private Sub Fire()  
    'Do your first action and after that start timer
    mTimer.Interval = 20
    mTimer.Start()
End Sub
```

This way you don't even bother with Mutex and locks.